# A subfield of $\mathbb C$ with a real imbedding and finite extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

If $\mathbb C/K$ is a finite extension of fields and there is an imbedding from $k$ to $\mathbb R$, my conjecture is $[\mathbb C:k]=1$ or $2$.

I need some idea. Thank you.

Comment: Are $C$ and $R$ supposed to be $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{R}$, the complex numbers and real numbers respectively?

Comment: does $C$ refer to the complex numbers? Does $R$ refer to the reals?

Comment: Wouldn't your conjecture be more precise and say $\,[\Bbb C:\Bbb k]=2\;$ since otherwise $\,\Bbb k\cong\Bbb C\;$ but then the real embedding is a problem?

Answer (score 3):

It turns out (see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_closed_field)) that if $[\mathbb{C}:K]$ is finite, then it is automatically equal to $1$ or $2$, no matter what. It is 1 if and only if $\mathbf{i} \in K$.

If there is a field homomorphism $K \to \mathbb{R}$, then $\mathbf{i} \notin K$, otherwise $\mathbb{R}$ would contain a square root of $-1$.